# My professor is asking us to find the semigroup reduct of the dihedral group D3, what is that?

Tags: semigroups, dihedral-groups, reductive-groups

Im not exactly sure what a semigroup reduct is, I know what a semigroup is but thats it, and im not exactly sure how to apply that to the dihedral group D3 anyway. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Look in your text, in the index if necessary, and search for the term.  Search on Google, or search on [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).  Notice that one reason to upvote a question is "shows research", and one reason to downvote it is "does not show research".  This site is not intended to be a "do-my-homework-for-me" site.

Comment: I dont intend to make it a do my homework for me, I was just asking for a definition as there isnt one in the book or our notes and google returns no results as far as i can find

Comment: Fair enough.  Please clarify that in your post.  Instead of "Can someone help me here?" maybe ask how they can help you:

Comment: Presumably you are doing a course about model theory or universal algebra. Have you looked in your course material for a definition of the term "reduct" (not "semigroup reduct")?

Comment: I did look but I will check again

Comment: Maybe you should ask your professor what she means by "semigroup reduct".

Comment: Any answer from your professor?

Comment: OK, I guess you've lost interest in the question.